# Using pip install from private gitlab repository, when building Docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, gitlab, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I am trying to build a docker image on an Ubuntu machine, where one of the dependencies is
an internally hosted Gitlab project (IT IS NOT HOSTED ON GITLAB.COM).

The docker file is:

```
FROM  rayproject/ray:1.12.0-py39-cpu
RUN git config --global user.name <MY USER NAME>
RUN git config --global http.sslVerify false
COPY .ssh/id_rsa /home/ray/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.ssh/*
RUN eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
RUN eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN pip install git+https://gitlab.<EMPLOYERS DOMAIN>.com/xyz/my_project.git
```

I am attempting to build the docker file with:

```
docker build .
```

I receive this error message when building the docker image:

```
Step 8/29 : RUN pip install git+https://gitlab.<EMPLOYERS DOMAIN>.com/xyz/my_project.git
 ---> Running in b9e11319c84d
Collecting git+https://gitlab.<EMPLOYERS DOMAIN>.com/xyz/my_project.git
  Cloning https://gitlab.<EMPLOYERS DOMAIN>.com/xyz/my_project.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-l1qklujg
  Running command git clone -q https://gitlab.<EMPLOYERS DOMAIN>.com/xyz/my_project.git /tmp/pip-req-build-l1qklujg
  fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.<EMPLOYERS DOMAIN>.com': No such device or address
WARNING: Discarding git+https://gitlab.<EMPLOYERS DOMAIN>.com/xyz/my_project.git. Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q https://gitlab.<EMPLOYERS DOMAIN>.com/xyz/my_project.git /tmp/pip-req-build-l1qklujg Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q https://gitlab.<EMPLOYERS DOMAIN>.com/xyz/my_project.git /tmp/pip-req-build-l1qklujg Check the logs for full command output.
```

However, from my machine, I can run

```
pip install https://gitlab.<EMPLOYERS DOMAIN>.com/xyz/my_project.git
```

without being asked to enter my username/password.

I'm unsure whether or not my machine was configured to use the RSA key to login into the internal Gitlab.

How can I install the package when building the docker image?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh` instead of `https`. i.e.

```
RUN pip install git+ssh://gitlab.<EMPLOYERS DOMAIN>.com/xyz/my_project.git
```

Comment: That does not work. The gitlab is only configured to accept https connections.

Answer (score 0):

Just to recall a security issue that wouldn't fit in a mere comment:

Every datum that we `COPY` within the Dockerfile is kept forever
(even if we do `RUN rm -fr something` afterwards!),
so this means here that anyone that can pull the Docker image can retrieve the contents of the `/home/ray/.ssh/id_rsa` file… to avoid this, two ways:

1. either do the cloning of the repo outside of the Dockerfile from GitLab-CI (then do a mere `COPY my_project my_project` then `RUN pip install ./my_project`)
2. or use the [`docker build --ssh`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds) feature.

Comment: @CatTerry did you have a look at one of the two solutions I suggested?